# React Native Flexbox adjustment for landscape orientation

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am working on making some UI elements for a React Native application.
I need these elements to work in both landscape orientation and portrait orientation.

I used Flexbox to organize the elements, which looks fine in portrait mode, but when I switch to landscape mode I get something that looks like this
[image]
, which I presume is due to the dimensions of the phone and thus the flexbox being changed when switching orientations

I am just wondering what is the best way to handle cases like this, I have seen some applications where different code is rendered based on the orientation of the device, but I am hoping to find a solution that doesn't require so much effort

Comment: It's not that clear what you're asking, but I don't think there's any solution that "just works" for everything. If you post your desired layout and what you've tried, someone may be able to help you get what you want with a minimum of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1-** You can use useWindowDimensions hook, which calculates width & hight automatically when we switch between landscape and portrait mode.

**const {width, height} = useWindowDimensions();**

**2-** Then, you can set a boolean variable to detect whether you're in landscape or not

**const isLandscapeMode = width > height? true : false;**

**3-** Now, you can switch between styles depending on **isLandscapeMode** variable

**<View style={{ width: isLandscapeMode? 400 : 300, you can add any other styling}}>**

if you don't prefer inline styles, you can also do this

**<View style={isLandscapeMode? styles.landscapeStyle : styles.portraitStyle}>**